# Does Law of Karma apply on animals/birds?

Tags: vedas, karma

I wanted to know whether Law of Karma applies on animals/birds and other non-human creatures? 
Since all the animals(if not all), are dependent on other animals/creatures for food/living; how the law of Karma justified when these animals kill other animals? 
Is there anything specified in our Vedas in this regards? Please share the link, if possible.

Comment: There is nothing that is not controlled by the Law of Karma, except God and the saints.

Comment: Answer: **No. Law of *Karma* doesn't apply to the muDha jiva i.e. non-humans.** ("Law of Karma" => Good/Bad/Mixed fruits based on *Karma*) Usually such lower births are "punishment" lives due to past. Actions performed under the complete influence of *Triguna* (material nature: *Sattva, Rajas, Tamas*) are according to *Swa-Dharma*; it doesn't generate any *KarmaFala* (also known as *Akarma*). Such *jiva*s don't attain *Moksha* despite of *"NishkAm Karma"*. Because with that, 1 level of detachment happens. Since animal consciousness is body level, the detachment happens from physical body only.

Answer (score 2):

Every being acts according to its own Guna and Swabhava and hence they are all subjected to law of Karma. Please refer to Manu Smriti.

In Verse 1.28-29, it says, all species of creatures have been allotted same kind of karmas that they were alloted in previous cycle of creation. Thus, species which were violent in previous creation are also violent in this etc.

1.30- it says, just as different seasons get their different characters naturally, similarly all animals develop Karmas suitable for them naturally.

1.41- says that Prajapatis have created all animals which are involved in their own karmas.

It gives more details from 1.42 verse onwards. More such references can easily be found.