# Do mentally ill people get karmaphala?

Tags: karma, advaita, maya

Is thinking that the body is the self a form of mental illness/disorder ?

If a Psychopath(alex) killed people but in his mind he thought that he actually helped the victims from some mysterious serial killers ,he even will  confuse when  police puts him under arrest  because he still thinks that the serial killers still exist around there to kill more people while according to police  actually it was him and no other people involved doing the acts....

His dementia made him not remembering the acts ,he even is  still searching for his glasses Even though he wears it all the time....

His schizophrenia made him seeing different reality he saw the victims as serial killers while according to police there were no victims to be saved at all they only existed in his mind

These kind of people can't differentiate between reality and dream and  you may say that they are crazy but they may actually think you are the one who are crazy here

If you still don't get the question please YouTube or Google  "fractured" or "shutter island" movie

What the most confusing thing to me is that mind itself can do karma too besides the body, and in that previous case his mind did good karma by saving people from serial murderers but according to the police's mind he did bad karma ,what is right here ?

It doesn't stop there... if the police said "sir ,you just hallucinated you never saved people instead you killed them the Psychopath will just say "alright ,maybe you are right but I think I still hallucinate even now so maybe you are unreal too let me finish you too..  after all you are just my hallucination aren't you ?"  So I don't think the police could ever convince him that he was guilty his argument was basically "I exist in my own reality ,there is no objective reality everything are subjective reality I can do everything because in my subjective world  whatever I do is right" what do you think about that paradox ?

This reminds me about quantum paradox that still makes scientists confused  basically at atomic level everything will have different state just because you observe it for example in a double slit experiment a photon will behave like particle but when you observe it they will instead behave like wave.. and only when you observe it they change their nature.. if you don't trust me you can Google it by yourself , it's mind-blowing isn't it ?

Now using advaita ,do "you" even have body and mind at all ? Do "you" have past karmaphala or any karmaphala at all ? Or can "you" state that "you" own everything including every karmaphala , every body and every mind ?

I think there is strong relation between psychology , science and advaita maybe you can correct me here too

I know we can't avoid doing karma but we can do karma without getting affected by the karmaphala(fruit) according to Sri Krishna

> Block quote
>   "The Atma-jnani is not bound by the results of Karma; it is only those who indulge in Karma without the awareness of the Atma, (their real Self, unaffected by what they do or feel or think) that do get bound. Like the person who has learnt swimming, the Jnani can safely wade into the sea of worldly activity. If you do not know swimming, but yet enter the sea, the waters will swallow you up and death is sure." Source : [geetha vahini chapter 4 written by sathya sai baba (geetha and Baba's commentary)](http://vahini.org/downloads/geethavahini.html)
>
> Block quote

And don't bother to answer this if you don't know advaita at all I just don't want you becoming more confused like me

Hence my question

Comment: this question has too many questions. try editing.

Comment: You can just answer only the first question I don't want to spam you with 40 questions on 40 threads here

Comment: what is basis of calling the presented view as an illness?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Is thinking that the body is the self a form of mental illness/disorder ?

Comment: It's just a question ,you don't need to answer it if you don't want

Comment: what is basis of calling the presented view as an illness?

Comment: Please read it all then you will know , it's an awesome question

Comment: this question has too many questions. try editing.

Comment: I don't force you to answer you can just answer the first question ,the other questions r just follow up small questions , it's not important but if you answer it I will pray for your goodness I don't want to waste your Time  by creating separate threads/posts just to answer the related questions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Law of Karma apply on animals/birds?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9227/does-law-of-karma-apply-on-animals-birds)

Comment: Nope ,how can animal make karma when they don't know about right or wrong ?

Comment: I mean even god does karma , it's the karmaphala that is questioned