# Who are not included in Paap or Punya system?

Tags: belief, karma, animals

The Paap and Puniya system is applicable to human beings because we have the power of reasoning. So does that mean that who doesn't have power of reasoning are not judged in this system?

For example - Animals, there are carnivorous animals that kill other animals for their survival. Killing others is Paap, so do carnivorous animals become Paapi? I don't think so but I want a confirmation. Am I thinking correctly?

Another question (out of curiosity) - a mentally challenged or mad person, since he doesn't have reasoning power, shouldn't be judged in this system? Is that correct? If yes, then if he commits some serious crime like murder then what happens?

Comment: Only grown up humans, devas and asuras experience karma.

Comment: This is a dup. of [Do mentally ill people get karmaphala?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40686/do-mentally-ill-people-get-karmaphala)

Comment: Whether a decision is taken from soul that is reasoning, intellect in wise sages, kings or by mere instincts of mind in animals or mad people, its the decision of self and leads to fruits of actions. The random decisions of animals have limited impact while of sages and kings/leaders have large impact. 'Hundred blows of goldsmith is comparable to one blow of iron-smith'. Judgement or some pending third party judgement day is a modern Abrahamic afterlife concept. Humans by nature have divine origin, Dharma/adharma are correct Vedic words for understanding Karma and fruits which are real time.